# Do it already, Stack Overflow in Ukrainian (uaSO)!

Tags: feature-request, area-51, languages, site-proposal

Do it already, uaSO!, it's already unrealistic for Ukrainian programmers to be in Stack Overflow in Russian.

As Ukrainian developers, we actively utilize the Russian-speaking Stack Overflow and appreciate the value it brings to the community. However, we believe it's time to establish a dedicated platform where we can share our expertise, discuss issues, and communicate in a language that resonates with our hearts.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361294/3001761, https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition

Comment: @jonrsharpe the reason why ruSO exists is that the developer is forced to know Russian

Comment: @ВадимАлександру nobody is being forced to learn a specific language. There are plenty of SO variants in SE. If you want to start your own, create a proposal on Area 51.

Comment: I fully accept that there are some concerns when it comes to usage of language for programming that I don't fully comprehend and I understand that creating space for Ukranian developers to program in that language may be well-received. But the post that jon linked to expressly discusses why we are no longer creating non-English sites. The overhead of supporting a site with UI that is in languages other than what we have is too high for us to do at this time, so we do not have plans to expand beyond the existing four non-English languages.

Comment: @Catija if the expenses are covered by Ukrainian developers?

Comment: Do it already uaSO what?

Comment: @user3840170 I *think* they're asking for the creation of a Ukrainian Stack Exchange, but that's not at all clear from the question.

Comment: @Catija I think that first sentence misses a point by a fair bit, given what's been happening on this planet for the last 1.5 years...

Comment: What about if you use the site using the English UI but allow questions in Ukranian? Another thing to consider is that it will require someone on the CM team and someone in the Support team to understand Ukrainian so they can handle affairs that require the CM / Support team's attention. It would help if you considered the required workings in case the insiders who understand Ukrainian can't longer be part of the company, how they will be substituted, etc.

Comment: [Are there any banned subjects on Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350157/are-there-any-banned-subjects-on-area-51) explains why the team isn't currently accepting proposals for non-English sites. TL;DR it's due to a lack of resources.

Comment: If you're willing to pay, you might as well go straight to a [Q&A alternative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37953/323179). With enough money (or volunteers) you could get someone to contribute localizations to any of the open source ones, since I doubt any have built-in support for Ukrainian.

Comment: The first sentence is nearly incomprehensible. Can you elaborate on what you mean? ("ruso" is probably a shorthand for Stack Overflow на русском)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum they mean that there is already Stack Overflow in Russian, they want there to be Stack Overflow in Ukrainian as well.

Comment: hmm... the author deleted the profile. Probably under downvote pressure

Answer (score 6):

I disagree that we need to create more non-English SO-like sites.  As a non-native English speaker, I believe people should learn English (or at least learn to use some translation program) and  contribute to SO, instead of continuing to fragment knowledge into several sites.

Comment: I agree that fragmenting knowledge across different sites is counterproductive, also: because programing is so English-heavy you're forced, at least during writing of a program, to learn English at some point.

Comment: People can also use tools like Google Translate to use English sites even if they are not native English speakers.  Not ideal of course, but it does help a lot.