# Is there a way to search all sites at once?

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation, search, global-search

I was just wondering if there were any posts already about which tablet would be the best buy for this holiday season.

I wasn't sure which site I should look on.

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) maybe? [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) maybe?

I would prefer an Android tablet, so maybe even [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)?

Then I thought, if only there were a way to search all Stack Exchange sites for a topic.

Maybe there is, and I don't know about it. If not, there should be.

Comment: There [is a method to search all Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61577/searching-multiple-stackexchange-sites-build-it-into-the-ui). As a fair warning, though, shopping advice isn't a traditional topic of questions and you probably won't find much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make the search box return results from all StackOverflowian sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/make-the-search-box-return-results-from-all-stackoverflowian-sites)

Comment: Google knows ...  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stackexchange%22+what+is+the+best+tablet+to+buy+for+the+holiday+season

Comment: I find Google produces more relevant results the query in this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298384/513519

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can search all of the sites from [StackExchange.com](http://stackexchange.com).  Look at the way top, to the right of the screen.

Or

https://stackexchange.com/search?q=

Comment: Unfortunately, that just does a Google search (e.g., it won't perform a "user:me something" search as SE's engine would). There's no way to use SE's built-in search engine?

Comment: @Geremia it was changed at some point to use SE search, though still user:me won't work, other operators like `is:q` do work.