# In stackoverflow, how do I list the questions that match my favorite tags?

Tags: discussion, meta

The question may be very simple, but I still don't know how. Thanks.

Comment: You can use Filters, see [this other answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160290/152859).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the search feature to turn up questions where more than one tag is applied:

```
 [tag1][tag2][tag3]
```

Then sort the results to your liking. However, there's no `or` operator that I know of. In other words, searching `[php][lisp]` isn't going to show you PHP or LISP questions, but questions tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php) *and* [lisp](/questions/tagged/lisp). That may change, as Stack Exchange is investing a lot of time and talent into the functionality and features of the search.

However, both the front page and the [questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) *should* be a rather nice blend of questions that are marked with some of your favorite tags. For now, I think that's the best you can find.

Comment: You can search by `or` now, e.g. `[jsf] or [jsf-2] or [jsf-2.2] or [jsf-1.2]` (http://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)

Answer (score 0):

Under questions, on the right navigation bar click on your favourite tag and there you go. Or search for tags and only those questions will come up

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. Moreover, can I select more than one tag?

Comment: as far as i know, i think at one time you can list questions of 1 tag. But my knowledge of SO is limitted so maybe someone else can guide us if you can select more tags at once

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot have multiple tags active at the same time.
when you choose a tag only the questions related to that particular tag will be displayed.