# TensorFlow Community is split into multiple sites

Tags: discussion, migration, community

We have:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tensorflow) with 19,072 questions
- [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tags/tensorflow) with 269 questions
- [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/tensorflow) with 255 questions
- [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tags/tensorflow) with 26 questions

I came across this issue when reading *[Intuitive explanation of Noise Contrastive Estimation (NCE) loss?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13216/intuitive-explanation-of-noise-contrastive-estimation-nce-loss)* on Data Science which duplicates the answer on *[How sampling works in Word2vec? Can someone please make me understand NCE and negative sampling?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244616/how-sampling-works-in-word2vec-can-someone-please-make-me-understand-nce-and-ne/245452#245452)*.

This is kind of annoying, and I'm not really sure what to expect as an answer here. Is there anything I can do except for searching across multiple sites?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61577/searching-multiple-stackexchange-sites-build-it-into-the-ui ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70331/is-there-a-way-to-search-all-sites-at-once ... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272817/is-there-a-place-to-search-several-all-stack-exchange-sites-at-once/272820#272820

Comment: Consider marking this as a duplicate of one of the above if it resolves your question, otherwise please explain further what you are looking for if not a cross-site search tool.