# Best practice for marking own questions that could belong on another/multiple sites

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Over the past couple of days there have been a few questions about overlapping proposals and questions that could belong on multiple sites:

- [How to deal with question that can find on many site ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61539/how-to-deal-with-question-that-can-find-on-many-site)
- [How should we handle duplicate proposals on area51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52011/how-should-we-handle-duplicate-proposals-on-area51)
- [Near-duplicate or “subset” proposals on Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54697/near-duplicate-or-subset-proposals-on-area-51)

What is the best practice before / after asking a question if you think your question might be better on another site?

or

If I think my question might belong on multiple sites as per the above posts?

Comment: The first rule of best-practice is that you don't talk about best-practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions are supposed to be asked and evaluated without regard to what site they would best be suited for.  From the Area51 FAQ:

> When voting, focus on your site. Don't
>   worry about whether a question might
>   be asked on another site. Your goal is
>   to make the best possible site for
>   *this* community.

Comment: Hi Robert, I was not thinking about proposals, as they have already been discussed in the topics above. But I mean when asking actual questions and not knowing which site they belong on.

Comment: See my edit....